# How to handle Angular 2+ (7) routing changes without refactoring?

Tags: angular, angular7

Right now, the recommended routing is to have a routes array that would look something like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component },  // can't use RouterStringService here I don't think...
    { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component }
]
@NgModule({...})
export class AppRouting Module {}
```

This is all good and well. We can use this to navigate:

- ts files - `router.navigate(['/page1'])`
- html files - `[routerLink]="/page1"`

Cool. This works great. However, what happens if we need to change `page1` to `home-feed` (or anything that's not `page1`)? Refactoring string literals is a pita and asking for problems (especially in html). We can use redirects like so:

```
// changes to above code block
{ path: 'page1', redirectTo: 'new-page1' },
{ path: 'new-page1', component NewPage1Component },
```

But this just adds the mental overhead of remembering redirects because other code references will still potentially be `router.navigate(['/page1'])`.

We can also use a service that's imported almost everywhere. This (unless I'm mistaken) wouldn't be usable within `appRoutes` because that's declared outside a module? (this is noted in the first code block)

```
export class RouterStringService {
    static page1: string = '/page1'
    static page2: string = '/page2

    // put string builders here too for things like /pageX/:id

    constructor() {}
}
```

How do you guys handle this? I know the refactoring isn't ideal, but there are times when it has to happen. I'm mostly worried about missing routing because angular 7 pushes using string literals. Do you use e2e testing to catch this or can you fix it programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also aim for avoiding string literals in the code, as much as possible for the reasons you mentioned. A good idea is to have configuration files(just like the environment.ts is for example), which serves as reference dictionary for the different url-s.

If you need to change the exact string literals, you can do so in one place.

Those configuration objects can be referenced from TS files, or from the HTML templates also, **if you export them** to the template in their corresponding component.

For instance:
`urls.ts` file somewhere in the assets or any other folder:

```
export const AppUrls = {
    base: "...",
    login: "...",
    ...
}
```

in ts files:

```
   import {AppUrls} from '..../urls.ts';

    const appRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo: AppUrls.login, pathMatch: 'full' },
```

in the templates, first you export it:

```
import {AppUrls} from '..../urls.ts';

@Component({
  selector: '...
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  AppUrls = AppUrls;
```

and in the html:

```
[routerLink]="{{AppUrls.login}}"
```

Also, `router.navigate(['/page1'])` does not need the slash and you can separate different urls as array entries: `router.navigate(['firstpart', 'secondpart'])` -> this will take you to `/firstpart/secondpart`

Comment: In this example, `AppUrls.base = '/'`, right? Then if you use multiple dictionaries (`AppUrls.base = '/'`, `UserUrls.base = '/users'`, `CameraUrls.base = '/camera'`) all you have to do is adjust the bases accordingly, right?

I also didn't know `router.navigate` supported arrays, thanks for that tidbit.

Comment: that was just some random placeholder I wrote. BaseURL should be defined in the index.html with the `  <base href="/">` tag, or, you can set it ina dynamic way with providing it in `providers` array, as it is described in here: http://www.projectcodify.com/angular-set-base-url-dynamically